# Find offset between two matrices

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have 2 binary (r x c) matrices - Matrix A & Matrix B of the same size. Matrix B is obtained by shifting the 1s in Matrix A by an offset value to the left/right/top/bottom.

```
int a[][] ={
            { 0,0,1,0,0 },
            { 0,1,0,1,0 }, 
            { 1,0,0,0,1 }
        }, 
        b[][] = 
        {
            { 0,0,0,1,0 },
            { 0,0,1,0,1 }, 
            { 0,1,0,0,0 }
        }
```

In this case, Matrix B is shifted by one row to the right. My goal is to find the offset (r+1 in this e.g) between the 2 matrices.

My solution - Add a column with all 0s to Matrix A and check if its equal to Matrix B. Continue adding c-1 columns. Repeat the same process for rows. Stop when the two matrices are equal.

This seems like a very inefficient way to do this. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see an edge case here which requires explanation.  What happens if a given matrix could have more than one equivalent shifted version?  How do we know which shift is acceptable?  Also, are you wrapping values around from the end of the matrix to the start?

Comment: Let's just say we need to find any one of the possible offsets? And I'm not wrapping values around (add a column/row of 0s when shifting)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your algorithm has a time complexity of O(rc^2). I can propose a solution that has a time complexity of O(rc) using hashing. 
I would be discussing how to solve the problem for the case when the matrix is shifted right by some columns. The same idea is applicable for the other three types of shifts too. One thing to notice is that, the way I understand, in your example, the second matrix is shifted by 1 column, not 1 row, since all the values are shifted by 1 column. I would be using this convention in the following solution.

Let's assume, we are given two 1xc matrices. Now, we can think of these as binary strings with c digits. We would hash both the strings and store the hash value for all the suffixes of the second string and all the prefixes of the first string using O(c) memory and O(c) time. Now, we can iterate for all possible shifts and check. For example, to check if the matrix is shifted by 3 columns, we can just check if the first three values of the second string are zero and if the (c-3) length suffix of the second string has the same hash value as the (c-3) length prefix of the first string in O(1). We would need to store the length of the longest zero prefix of the second string to make this work efficiently before starting the iteration.

Now, when we have a rxc matrix, we can hash each column of both the matrices and then transform a rxc matrix into a 1xc string where the i-th digit of the string would be equal to the hash value of the i-th column of the matrix and apply the above algorithm in the same way.